# how to detect if an actionitem is overflowed

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

How can I check whether a menuitem is overflowed in the actionbar?

I haven't found a method that could do it.

Comment: I don't know, but I'm curious why you would want to determine that. Aren't all menu items created equal? :)

Comment: Haha, I don't remember now. I think it was a backward-compatibility thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it programmatically, and I struggle to find a use case where this would be a good idea from a UX standpoint, but the [Android Design docs](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html) have been updated with a guide to how many icons will be shown for a given device size.

[image: http://developer.android.com/design/media/action_bar_pattern_table.png]